# Showing a function is differentiable using the defition

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I'm working on the following exercise in order to practice differential calculus:

> Suppose $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is of class $C^1$. Let $F:\mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be given by:
>
> $$F(x, y)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
> \frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x} \text{, if }x\neq y\\ 
> f'(x)\text{, if }x=y
> \end{matrix}\right.$$

Show that $F$ is differentiable on $(x, y)$ whenever $x \neq y$. If there exists $f''$, show that $F$ is differentiable on $(x, x)$ for all $x$.

I have proven that $F$ is differentiable whenever $x \neq y$. Also, I already have calculated the partial derivatives of $F$ on $(x, x)$. They are:

$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}=\frac{f''(x)}{2}$$

So it remains to show that:

$$\lim_{(h, k)\rightarrow 0}\frac{F(x+h, x+k)-F(x, x)-\frac{f''(x)}{2}(h+k)}{\|(h, k)\|}=0$$

And this is where I am stuck. How do I compute this limit?

Edit: If i can prove that the limit above holds restricted to $h \neq k$, then I know how to prove that the limit above holds. Therefore it remains to show that:

$$\lim_{(h, k)\rightarrow 0, h \neq k}\frac{\frac{f(x+k)-f(x+h)}{k-h} -f'(x)-\frac{f''(x)}{2}(h+k)}{\|(h, k)\|}=0$$

Comment: Don't you need a factor of $1/2$ in front of the $f''(x)$ term in your limit?

Comment: Yes, i made a typo! :)

Comment: You have a typo. One of the $f$'s should be $F.$